# What's the best media server solution for RPi4 for remote watching?

Tags: media-server

Kind of hard to ask, but the idea is that: I have a RPi4(8 GB) with RaspberryPiOS, and i have a few things mounted on it that are working perfectly and i need to keep working correctly. Now, i would like to also use this RPi to be able to access media files(Series, movies), and if possible, that it doesn't consume all the resources, reason as to why i'm trying to search for a solution that lets me access the file through the Network, and play it on another device without the file having to be copy-pasted to that device(With an Android App), and not play it on the RPi and stream it to the other.

Not sure if something like this exist, i've seen some options like Plex, but i readed that Plex stream the content to the app on another device(Also Plex seems to consume too many resources since it scans very constantly searching for changes). Does someone know of an application that works this way, or a way to mount something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend Plex (https://www.plex.tv) its is free to use and supports Movies, TV, Photos and Music playback.

It can support multiple backends (so you can spread your media around on multiple boxes) and these are all accessible via a Play server.

Its extremely well supported and it can be run on anything form a smartphone to a PS4.

Its not bloated and it doesn't waste network bandwidth..  ou can configure it to not do periodic checks for new files. You can turn off the automatic directory scanning feature if it bothers you and preform the update manually.

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted, but until i get another option, this seems to be the best, just would be good if there was any guide to deactivate any service not completely necessary.  Thanks.